# Efficient way of dividing a querySet with a filter, while keeping all data?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a 'Parts' model, and these parts are either linked to a 'Device' model or not yet. The actual "link" is done via more than just one ForeignKey, i.e. I have to go through 3 or 4 Models all linked between each other with ForeignKeys to finally get the data I want.

My question is: What is the most efficient way of getting both the linked and non-linked parts ?

Right now, I am getting all parts and simply outputting that, but I would like a little separation:

```
allParts = Parts.object.all()
```

I know I could do something similar to this:

```
allParts = Parts.object.all()
linkedParts = allParts.objects.filter(...device_id=id)
nonLinkedParts = allParts.objects.exclude(...device_id__in=[o.id for o in linkedParts])
```

But is that really the most efficient solution ? I feel like there would be a better way, but I have not yet found anything in the docs about it.

Just to clarify, there are only linked, and non-linked parts. These are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think your solution is pretty efficient.
You can surely (using F and Q operators in Django) combine the filter and the exclude query in just one query for (possible) speedup.

The .all() query is just not needed. Keeping or removing that won't make any difference anyway, because Django's ORM is lazy, so your first query (allParts) is never actually executed. Another hint: camel case is not best practice in python ;).

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in obtaining the elements, for example to iterate over it, you can work with two lists:

```
allParts = Parts.object.all()
linkedParts = []
nonLinkedParts = []

for part in allParts:
    if part.device_id == id:
        linkedParts.append(part)
    else:
        nonLinkedParts.append(part)
```

since these are lists, you can no longer (efficiently) filter further, or order by a specific condition. If you want to order it by a certain field, you should do that already in the `allParts` database query.

Comment: Are you sure this is more efficient than two queries based on a single column?

Comment: @ManuelFedele: yes, since we need to fetch all the data anyway (we can do this with one or two queries), and typically the *number* of queries is a better estimate that the *content* of the query.